# "Value of '2' is not valid for 'index'" error when setting value to '0'

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to set the selected index of a ComboBox to 0 in my VB.Net form.

Here is the line of code that is causing the error:

```
Me.CBB_Version.SelectedIndex = UBound(WorkpackageVersions)
```

In this particular case, there is only one element in the WorkpackageVersions array; meaning the UBound is 0.

Even if I change the line to read:

```
Me.CBB_Version.SelectedIndex = 0
```

I get the error; "Value of '2' is not valid for 'index'"

If I check in the immediate window in Visual Studio; the ComboBox has 1 item inside it; and the selected index is "-1", so nothing is currently selected.

- If I 'continue' after the error in debug mode, and try running the line again - it works perfectly.
- If I place a breakpoint before this line, and run it in the Immediate window; it produces this same error, but works if I run it a second time.

I can only assume it is failing because it's trying to set the index to a value of 2 (when there is one element, not three), as the error suggests.

But how is this possible when I hard-code a 0?

Comment: Is there some default value floating around? Without the entire package this is hard to debug for you; but if you tried to create the smallest self-contained example that demonstrates the behavior, you may find you actually solve the problem yourself...

Comment: check that there is not something going on in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event

Comment: Thanks Plutonix - I solved the problem just before seeing your comment but you nailed the problem.

Comment: As a tip for the future. If you Go to Debug > Exceptions and check the tick box in the "Thrown" column for "Common Language Runtime Exceptions". Then you will be prompted the line that actually causes the issue. Should make it easier to find the issue. Remember to turn it of again though since it will do this in try catch blocks to etc. Might be annoying :)